# Project Help For 12 volts output Buck Converter

Tags: voltage-regulator, pwm, dc-dc-converter

So we are building a 12 volts output buck converter with 17 volts input for our project.
And i was wondering if using LM317 as regulators and NE 555 for the PWM generator a good idea.thanks.

Comment: What is the required current compliance and what is the expected current dynamic range? (Or, what's the minimum load and what's the maximum load?)

Comment: I forgot to add thats its for battery charging 12 Volts.

Comment: You can buy a buck converter controller IC. This will make the process much easier.

Answer (score 0):

The LM317 is a linear regulator with no correlation to a buck converter.

An NE555 is not a practical element for pulse width modulation required of a buck converter.

There are hundreds of special purpose ICs made specifically to be the heart of a buck converter. You should review the available application notes and choose one that satisfies your requirements.